# Run Chrome using IPv6

Tags: linux, centos, google-chrome

In my Windows 11 machine and in my CentOS 9 stream I have 2 IPs assigned: one is IPv4 and another is IPv6. I can use both IPs on these computers and it works fine.

When I use Chrome, by default it uses IPv4 to make all requests (every website I access chrome will use IPv4).

So I ask you: is there any Chrome switch/flag that I can set in order to make it use the IPv6 by default?

I think this is not a case of proxy, right? I already have both IPs available on these computers, I am wondering if there is a command line that I can use to start Chrome and make it use IPv6.

Comment: What are you using to determine which IP is used? Do you have something like [IPvFoo](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ipvfoo/ecanpcehffngcegjmadlcijfolapggal?pli=1) installed in your browser to tell you? For most page elements, Chrome already prefers IPv6 over IPv4.

Comment: a single IPV6? Is that a public IPv6 or are you seeing a link local address?

Comment: I have a public IPV6 that I want chrome to use instead of the IPV4. Both IPs are available in my server but for some reason Chrome picks up IPV4.

Comment: The correct spelling of those words is “Merry” and “Christmas”, but it was unnecessary to say that statement, so I went ahead and removed it

Comment: Are you sure the *sites* you are browsing to support IPv6?

Comment: Also, maybe check with [test-ipv6.com](https://test-ipv6.com/) if *you* are properly set up.

Comment: To insist: "I have a public IPV6". Currently if it doesn't start with the digit 2, it's not public. So does it start with 2? If it starts with f, it's not public so chrome can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, both Firefox and Chrome will prefer IPv6 over IPv4 but will have a quick fail-over ("Happy Eyeballs") to the other protocol if the DNS request had returned addresses of both protocols and the response using the first protocol takes too long.